# Upgrade PHP Version on CentOS-7

Tags: php, linux, centos7

Hello Linux Professional,

Hope everybody doing well. I am bit new to the Linux. I have a task to upgrade PHP on Centos. There are some Drupal sites are hosted on them. The upgrade will be from PHP 5.x.x to PHP 7.4. It is a major upgrade. Is there any recommended way to get this Job done.

Secondly, On what factors should i be careful of, In terms of security, compatibility or any other things.

Thank you so much

Regards,

Raja

Comment: Upgrading PHP shouldn't be that difficult, you will have to read Drupal manuals for an upgrade guide.

Comment: First read the PHP upgrade notes **for each individual version upgrade** before doing anything. I would suggest checking the Drupal sites version is compatible with PHP7.4 before doing anything. Basically I would start by setting up a test environment and do it all there first.